# Why does my Django Forms Input only render when the submit button is clicked?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am currently making a Django forms for the first time and encountered a problem with rendering the text inputs of the forms. I used a simple template for my forms and attached a submit button along with the input.

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I used a `TemplateView` in my views.py to name the template and render the forms:

```
class HomeView(TemplateView):
template_name = "WebApp/index.html"

def post(self, request):
    form = HomeForms()
    return render(
        request,
        self.template_name,
        {
            'form': form,
            'title': 'Home',
        }
    )
```

And my forms.py currently looks like this:

```
from django import forms


class HomeForms(forms.Form):
    post = forms.CharField()
```

Furthermore, what would the differences be if I used `def get(self, request)` as opposed to `def post(self, request)`?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Because you don't pass anything to the context when it's a GET, so `{{ form }}` is not defined. Really, you should use a proper FormView, and don't define `get` or `post` at all.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing form to context. Instead TemplateView use FormView. It will work better for you.

Check the FormView implementation.

from django.views.generic.edit import FormView

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/